# Syntax error: bad input '' in codeskulptor

Tags: python, codeskulptor

Sometimes when I load a particular codeskulptor program that gives me the 
error: Syntax error: bad token '' on a line of code, what is wrong?

Note: This is a different question, I know I asked a similar question before but this is a different issue.

Comment: Please, post a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I generally consider this as a bug in codeskulptor. When this happens, you probably copied that line of code, You could just delete and rewrite the exact same line of code. If it works then you're set, if it doesn't then there is a bug in your code but most likely won't be on that very line.

Comment: Did you answer your own question?

Comment: Yup, you could do that

Comment: Maybe a weird space is in your code.
And when you copy-paste, this space disappear.

Comment: I've seen this a couple of times in my code and everytime I rewrite it exactly, the bug disappears.